# I can't run a program that uses allegro5 with cmake

Tags: c++, g++, cmake, allegro5

EDIT: If you want to look at the code, here it is:
https://github.com/WalterCapa/PercolationCpp/tree/master

I'm making a program that uses **allegro5** library to generate an animation.
Because i want to avoid the installation of the library on every computer that uses the program, i tried to paste the headers and the .so files in my project dir. So the tree is like this:

root

```
include
  allegro5  <- (Dir where the headers of allegro are)
  Percolation.h
  QuickUnion.h

lib
  allegro5  <-(Dir where the .so files are)
  Percolation.cpp
  QuickUnion.cpp

PercolationVisualizer <- (Dir that has the main)
```

The problem is this. I **installed** allegro5 in my pc with LinuxMint 13. Everything is fine if I compile from Code::Blocks or if I do it from the terminal using -I to call the hedaers and -L to tell where the .so files are, and even using cmake works fine, but when i try to do it in another computer, even if it's windows like my laptop or a virtual machine with linuxmint, it generates this error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target  '/./lib/allegro5/liballegro.so/', needed by'
../bin/PercolationVisualizer'.   Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PercolationVisualizer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
    project(PercolationCpp)

    set(PercolationCpp_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
    set(PercolationCpp_VERSION_MINOR 1)

    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ../bin/)

    set(percolation_SRCS PercolationVisualizer/PercolationVisualizer.cpp lib/Percolation.cpp lib/QuickUnion.cpp)

    #Executable 
    add_executable(PercolationVisualizer  ${percolation_SRCS})

    #include Allegro
    include_directories(./include)
    link_directories(./lib/allegro5)
    #connect all the libraries
    set(allegro5_LIBS /./lib/allegro5/liballegro.so /./lib/allegro5/liballegro_primitives.so)

    target_link_libraries(PercolationVisualizer ${allegro5_LIBS})
```

Btw, when trying it on windows with MinGW i used cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. and mingw32-make.
It found the compiler and and cmake worked, but when i tried de second one it gave me the same error. In my desktop i'm compiling using g++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your actual problem is the leading `/` in this line:

```
set(allegro5_LIBS /./lib/allegro5/liballegro.so /./lib/allegro5/liballegro_primitives.so)
```

A leading slash will tell `cmake` to look for an absolute path (like /usr/lib...) and not prefix it with a `CMAKE_*_DIR`. Try this

```
set(allegro5_LIBS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/allegro5/liballegro.so ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/allegro5/liballegro_primitives.so)
```

However I strong discourage you to include pre-built libraries in your project. If you can, integrate a tar-ball or a git-submodule. If the project you include is a cmake project itself, a simple call to `add_subdirectory` will make the targets (libraries usually) available to your project and create a dependency. If the project is based on configure you can use the [ExternalProject](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html)-extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for the linux mint virtual box. I didn't try with the laptop yet. But i only tried the first option. What are the problems with including pre built libraries? RIght now i'm reading about add_subdirectory, again thanks for your answer

Comment: Compiled objects as well as libraries are generated for a certain platform. A simple example is that a libary compiled for a 64bit architecture won't work on 32bit one. A library for ARM won't work on a i386-PC. The glibc-ABI-version might differ. To name some reasons.

Comment: I saw from your reputation, that you're quite new to SO. Please do not forget to upvote and accept an answer, once you will be able to. Welcome to SO.

Comment: haha yeah, i'm new, this is my first question but i was lurking the site for some time, so i know the mechanics. But i didn't choose the answer yet because i wasn't sure about some things. But yours definitely solved the problem and gave me useful info about things i should know and take in account. Thanks